# How to save YouTube downloaded video to phone gallery

Tags: google, youtube

I have downloaded a youtube video in my youtube app and I want to save this video to my phone gallery. What steps should I have to follow to do this?

Comment: Do you mean using Youtube Premium? I am pretty sure you can only watch it through the Youtube app and it won't show in the gallery, it has DRM which prevents it from being played outside of the Youtube app. If you are doing this some other way, please provide more details on how you are downloading it, etc.

Comment: Use [NewPipe](https://newpipe.schabi.org/).

Comment: I'm closing this as a dupe of "download YouTube video" because the only way to get it into phone gallery is by *not* downloading from YouTube app due to DRM protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Y2mate for this purpose. All you need to do is to open the web site and paste video url in it. Rest will be done automatically.

https://y2mate.com/

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Termux and youtube-dl python script. Here you have steps to install required software.

1. Install Termux https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux
2. Run Termux and paste following commands:

`apt update`

`apt install python`

`pip install youtube-dl`

Now you can download movies from YT

`youtube-dl <link to YouTube movie>`

But this is not comfortable way. Here are more steps to make it more user friendly.

1. Create dir in home:

`mkdir ~/bin`

2. Create file with your favorite editor. My is `vim` so I used it

`vim ~/bin/termux-url-opener`

3. Paste following content:

`youtube-dl $1`

and save file.

4. Make file executable:

`chmod 700 ~/bin/termux-url-opener`

5. Make Termux internal storage accessible.

`termux-setup-storage`

Accept access for Termux to internal storage

6. Create config file for youtube-dl:

`mkdir -p ~/.config/youtube-dl`

`vim ~/.config/youtube-dl/config`

7. Paste following config:

`-o /data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/movies/%(uploader)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s`

Now if you want to save movie from YT simply open YouTube app, find movie, tap Share and choose Termux.

[image: screenshot of youtube share window]

Movie will be saved in Movies directory in internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube gives you an option to download Videos to Watch them Offline later. These videos get saved in encrypted ‘.exo’ format that can only be opened with YouTube App.

So, If you want to use it with Other Media Player, you have to download it on your Android Device. Get the best way to do it, Below:

Step 1: First Download & Install: TubeMate YouTube Downloader App on your Android Device [from here](http://tubemate.net/)

Step 2: Launch TubeMate App &. Tap on ‘3 Horizontal Bar’ icon from Top Left Corner and Go with ‘Youtube’.

Step 3: Now search for any video on YouTube that you want to download.

Step 4: Once you run any video, you can download that video by simply ‘Tapping’ on ‘Green Download Icon’ from the Top.
To Get Full Pictorial Guide: Check Out Here NOW… [here](https://www.mashnol.org/download-clip-from-website/amp/)

Step 5: It will give you the option to download that video in different quality. Select the desired Quality and Tap on ‘Green Download icon’ from the bottom.

Note: Google considers that downloading YouTube Videos without authors permission is illegal. That’s why All YouTube Videos Downloading App has been removed from Google Play Store. Use TubeMate YouTube Downloader App to save a copy only for backup.

Comment: TubeMate uses 6 ad services and 2 analytics services. It asks for 16 Android permissions including location and 4 Google services permissions. Reads identifiers for analytics and tracking. NewPipe has 0 ad services, 0 analytics and asks for 7 necessary Android permissions in total.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by copying the **video link ** and copy that link on
**savefrom.net ** site. 
You will be able to do it successfully